# Checking for duplicate numbers in a random array

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have an array filled with random numbers. I want to check if there are any duplicate numbers in the array but I am getting problems. This is what I have so far :

```
Random randomNum=new Random();        
int[] array = new int[100];
for(int i = 0; i <  array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = randomNum.nextInt(100); //0-99
    System.out.print(array[i] + "  ");
}

for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    if(array[index] == array[index+1])
    System.out.println("Match in"+array[index]);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to do it "by hand" or are you willing to use library functions? Sorting the array is usually the first step, because duplicate detection is really easy on sorted arrays. (This is what you already do, but you have to iterate to `array.length -1` or you'll get an IndexOutOfBound exception.

Comment: I want to do it by hand just to learn the process.  The idea is to find the duplicates and their index location.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the HashSet to find duplicate values, since it doesn't accept duplicates.

```
    Random randomNum = new Random();
    int[] array = new int[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = randomNum.nextInt(100); // 0-99
        System.out.print(array[i] + "  ");
    }
    Set<Integer> rnd = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i : array) {
        if (!rnd.add(i)) {
            System.out.println(i + " is a duplicate");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code failed because you tried to access element after last in array: The last one is  `array[array.length - 1]`, but you tried `array[array.length]` when call `array[index+1]` and your index is already last `array.length - 1 + 1` = `array.length`. To fix it, just go to prelast element.

```
Random randomNum=new Random();        
 int[] array = new int[100];
 for(int i = 0; i <  array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = randomNum.nextInt(100); //0-99
    System.out.print(array[i] + "  ");
 }

for(int index = 0; index < array.length - 1; index++)
{
  if(array[index] == array[index+1]) 
  {
    System.out.println("Match in "+array[index]);
  }
}
```

But, I think this code will not solve your issue because it will find only neighbor dublicates. If you need all dublicates, you need double loop:

```
Random randomNum=new Random();        
 int[] array = new int[100];
 for(int i = 0; i <  array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = randomNum.nextInt(100); //0-99
    System.out.print(array[i] + "  ");
 }

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
  for(int j = i+1; j < array.length; j++) {
    if(array[i] == array[j]) {
      System.out.println("Match in "+array[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I see now.  In the inner loop.  Just by initializing j to the next index position and seeing if they match.  Thank you, this helps a lot!